# Subtracting from pointer to get length

Tags: c, pointers

I wanted to find the length of a part of a string after searching for it within a bigger string.

I cannot use strlen since I am dealing with binary data.

```
char *temp= "this is some random text";
char *temp1 = strstr(temp,"some");
int len = strlen(temp);
int len1 =0;

len1 = temp+len - temp1;
```

to get length of "some random text"

len1 returns negative value (even the positive value of it is wrong)

Comment: `temp1 - temp + len`; strpos better

Comment: @JoopEggen The value with ur suggestion is greater than len !!

Comment: When I run the example, I get `len1 == 16`, which is what I expect.  How do you figure `len1` is negative?

Comment: `"some random text" = strllen(temp1)` Previous comment was a misread.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  This is not the exact program I am running, it is part of my code, and I just gave the sample

Comment: Well, it's hard to figure out what might be going wrong when the example you give doesn't go wrong.

Comment: You're already using `strlen()` in your example.  Could you clarify the rules, or what you're looking for?  As it stands, `strstr(temp, "some")` will return a pointer to the NUL-terminated string `"some random text"` and you could call `strlen()` on that.  If you wanted to know the length of just the matching part, it's `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final answer**:

You're looking for `len - (temp1 - temp)`. The length of the first part is `temp1 - temp`. Substract it from the length of the entire string to get the length of the remaining part.

**Longer answer**:

Since `strlen` (which is what you have used in your example, even if it only works for proper text messages) goes until it finds a `\0` character you can simply use `strlen(temp1)` for the length of the last part of the input. If you are really concerned that calling `strlen` twice will harm your performance (really?) then you can use `len - (temp1 - temp)`.

You only need to do pointer substraction if you are interested in the length of the first part of the input.

If you want to work with binary arrays which contain `\0` in them at non-terminal position you *cannot* use `strlen` at all in your code. However, you have to have a way to specify the length of the entire input. Either you have this in an integer variable or you have a specific delimiter an a length-computing function.

If you have the integer variable for length then, since the length of the first part of the input is obtained by pointer substraction, you only have to do `len - (temp1 - temp)`.

If you have a length-computing function, simply call it with `temp1` as argument.

**PS**: Don't forget to check if `strstr` returns NULL (by the way, you cannot use `strstr` if you have binary data with `\0` inside the buffer)

Comment: Edited the answer to also include this case (which was not obvious from the way you've phrased your question)

Comment: strlen() is not free. It has a runtime cost. Since strlen() was already called on temp(), pointer arithmetic is perfectly appropriate. There's nothing to gain from calling strlen() twice.

Comment: Fixed this as well. Though I highly doubt that calling strlen twice will harm performance in normal use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not NULL-terminated, then you cannot call strstr() on it for the same reason you can't call strlen(). If you do that, you can end up scanning past the end of your data. If you find a match there (which is quite possible; reading past the end of arrays is not guaranteed to crash the program), then your pointer arithmetic *is* going to give you a negative value, because you're subtracting a larger address from a smaller one.

On the other hand, if your data is actually properly NULL-terminated, then your problem is probably that strstr() doesn't find the substring and thus returns NULL. Are you checking for NULL? Otherwise, what you end up doing is:

```
len1 = temp + len - (char*)NULL;
```